# Strip symbols while retaining unstripped binary in xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode, symbols, strip, symbolicatecrash

I am stripping symbols in Xcode 4.5, but realised that if we strip them we cannot symbolicate crash reports. So I am trying to create a copy of the unstripped binary before stripping. It seems this isn't possible with the normal xcode symbol stripping settings, so I've tried digging into run scripts. The problems I have there is

a) It seems the run script runs after code signing, so the app fails to run.

b) I can't find a way to run a run script under distribution/release only.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can symbolicate crash reports when the binary is stripped! Stripping the binaries makes them 30-50% smaller. Symbolicating with unstripped binaries would **not** give you line numbers after symbolication anyway.

During the build process you also get a dSYM package which is then used instead to symbolicate your crash reports including getting line numbers in them!

In addition, whenever you do a new build, you get a new unique pair of app binary and dSYM package, so you should use archive instead of build when you are releasing a beta or production version.